# How to run single sample randomly from set of multiple samples in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, web-api-testing

I have a "Thread Group" which has 10 "HTTP Requests". I want to execute any one of them in each thread randomly,

```html
Tag Image
Tag Image
Tag Image
Tag Image
Tag Image
Tag Image
Tag Image
Tag Image
Tag Image
Tag Image
```

I have these 10 requests, each of them containing different image tags in body.

As I want to add different tags randomly to my images, I want my JMeter script to run any of those request single time in each thread. Is it possible with JMeter? and How?

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you **really** want (I doubt that the scenario is valid cause I believe that tests needs to be repeatable) - you can put your Samplers which are adding tags under the [Random Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller)

[image]

Going forward I don't think having 10 requests which are adding different tags is a good idea, I think a single request would be sufficient and externalized using the [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) and the tags could be parameterized using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

Comment: so what Random counter does, it executes all samples in random order. In my scenario, I want to run any one of those requests randomly in each thread. Don't want to run all samples. If i use CSV data set it would iterate all tags listed in CSV equally. I want to add few tags 10 times few tag 5 times or few tags 1 time. If you could help provide a better solution of it please.

Comment: If you take a closer look you will see that **each thread** is kicking off a random tag ([threadNum() function returns the ID of current thread](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II)), if you replicate the test plan and set the number of threads to 1 - you will see only 1 random child executed.